# sp_addUser through sp_execute (SQL) in master db

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

The task is to automate restoring a group of databases, fixing orphaned users, and granting `SELECT`/`INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` permissions.

```
use master
go

ALTER DATABASE [myDatabase] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
    RESTORE DATABASE [myDatabase] FROM  DISK = N'D:\MSSQL\Backups\myDatabase.bak' WITH  FILE = 1
    ,  MOVE N'myDatabase' TO N'D:\MSSQL\Data\myDatabase.mdf'
    ,  MOVE N'myDatabase_log' TO N'D:\MSSQL\Logs\myDatabase.ldf'
    ,  NOUNLOAD
    ,  REPLACE
    ,  STATS = 5
ALTER DATABASE [myDatabase] SET MULTI_USER
go

use myDatabase
go

sp_adduser 'userSelectOnly'
go

exec sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'userSelectOnly'
go

grant select to userSelectOnly
go
```

Like this, in SSMS, it works great. Since there are several users and several databases, I'd like to put the database names and users into tables and loop through each, e.g.

```
    select @sql = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @dbname + '] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE'

    + 'RESTORE DATABASE [' + @dbname + '] FROM  DISK = N''D:\MSSQL\Backups\' + @dbname + '.bak'' WITH  FILE = 1
        ,  MOVE N''' + @dbname + ''' TO N''D:\MSSQL\Data\' + @dbname + '.mdf''
        ,  MOVE N''' + @dbname + '_log'' TO N''D:\MSSQL\Logs\' + @dbname + '.ldf''
        ,  NOUNLOAD
        ,  REPLACE
        ,  STATS = 5'

    + 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @dbname + '] SET MULTI_USER'' -- extra tick to fix the SE code highlighter

    exec sp_executeSQL @sql

    @sql = 'use ' + @dbname
    exec sp_executeSQL @sql

    select @sql = 'grant select to ' + @current_loop_user
    exec sp_executeSQL @sql
```

Followed by all the login/user lines. I've tried it, and it neither do the job nor throw obvious errors, am I going to just have to type it all out longhand?

Comment: Execute `use dbname` and `grant select to` in one command, I think it helps.

Comment: Side note, use `ADD USER` instead of the deprecated `sp_adduser` to add database users.

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamic text is not valid:

you should add spaces between `IMMEDIATE` and `RESTORE`, `STATS = 5` and `ALTER`,
you should remove additional unclosed quotation mark here: `SET MULTI_USER''` --> `SET MULTI_USER'`

Your

```
@sql = 'use ' + @dbname
    exec sp_executeSQL @sql
```

is executed in it's own context so you changed `db context` not for your `session` but only within your dynamic code execution so your next piece of dynamic code that grants is still executed in the context of current `database`.

You should always `print` your dynamic code before try to execute it and you'll see where the errors are.

But the best solution for your situation is to write once a plain(not dynamic) code for all databases, save it and run every time you need it.